# Drivers for e-STUDIO 2540 CSE

Tags: printing

I've been searching for the drivers of my printer Toshiba e-STUDIO 2540 CSE for about an hour and I haven't found anything. But I think they do exist because right here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-filters/+bug/978120/comments/45 someone says they were able to print something with it.

Could you please help me find the drivers for my printer?
PS : I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 32bits.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTX. Our office has a Toshiba e-Studio 2050c, it was printing perfectly with the open source standard driver and suddenly stopped. I searched for Linux drivers without luck and finally tried ones for other e-Studio models.

This one worked - http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Toshiba/Toshiba-e-Studio_2830c

D/l'd the .ppd file - removed and reinstalled the printer, selecting "supply .ppd file". Back in business, good luck.